# Are "IsFalse" and "IsTrue" basically just implicit conversion to boolean?

Tags: .net, vb.net, operators, comparison-operators, short-circuiting

Are "IsFalse" and "IsTrue" basically just implicit conversion to boolean ? I know they are used by the short-circuiting operators (AndAlso, OrElse), but are they any different in functionality or inner-workings then implicit conversion to boolean ?

Answer (score 2):

There are *explicit* conversions to Boolean.

You can only use them in your code to define the `= True` or `= False` evaluation of a structure you have written, so you have to define the rules to determine what value of your structure would equal true or false

```
Public Structure p
    Dim a As Double
    Public Shared Operator IsFalse(ByVal w As p) As Boolean
        Dim b As Boolean
        ' Insert code to calculate IsFalse of w.
        Return b
    End Operator
    Public Shared Operator IsTrue(ByVal w As p) As Boolean
        Dim b As Boolean
        ' Insert code to calculate IsTrue of w.
        Return b
    End Operator
End Structure
```

The return value of these Operators must be either True or False

See this page for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6tz4ad8.aspx

Comment: These methods seem a little unhealthy. I didn't even know they existed. If I  saw code like "if myStruct AndAlso myOtherStruct then" my first reaction would be to check if someone forgot to turn on strict compiling. What's odd is that a struct can evaluate to true or false but you have to look at its implementation to figure out what logic determines whether it's true or false. Whatever that logic is, I'd rather just test for that explicitly.